# Set ${env.MINGW_PREFIX} variable on VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I'm using ${env.MINGW_PREFIX} for debugging purposes in launch.vs.json .
Do you know how can I change the value (directory path) assigned to this variable?

Answer (score 0):

Start your visual studio with a bat-file beside yourSolution.sln like startVS.bat

```
@echo off
set MINGW_PREFIX=C:\Some\Random\Path
set TF_BUILD=True
start yourSolution.sln
```

It works for me with the TF_BUILD, not tested with json. Still waiting for a build-in solution from MS, to set multiple variables for debug-purpose:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/178737/visual-studio-2017-setting-environment-variables-f.html